# All male politicians dead

Tags: politics, government, gender, cataclysms, governance

All the male politicians have died in their sleep within a 24 hour period. Assuming no male will enter politics again, what will be the implications of this in different countries around the world primarily in regards to line of succession? Would any countries collapse and what measures might the surviving members of governments use to restaff the senate, parliament, etc? 
Any head of state counts as a politician including Monarchs.

Comment: This is pretty much entirely opinion-based, which makes it an unsuitable question for Worldbuilding.

Comment: How this happened would likely have a big impact on how the world reacts to it. Were they all murdered? Is there a virus that selectively kills male politicians?

Comment: What happens in the future would depend on your male-killing thing defines "male". Unless it was a one-time thing, then everything goes back to how it was fairly quickly with a side of intensified misogyny. I do think this could be an interesting question to explore but you should explore it first and then ask whether or not we think it's plausible. (Might still be too opinion-based even then.)

Comment: about your edit: politicians don't have a line of succession like monarchs. They are normally elected.

Comment: Your assumption makes no sense. If there is someone killing politicians, police forces all around the world would try to figure out this case. Also, suspects are forbidden (or "discouraged") from starting in elections in many jurisdictions, and who is more suspected than woman politicians in  such   scenario?

Comment: Why will no males enter politics? It would take repeated deaths of male politicians to discourage them. Not just one generation, but every subsequent cohort of male politicians. The answer is simple. Women will become the politicians and the world will go on as before. This suggests an intelligent agent is responsible for slaying all male politicians. Interesting to know how it was done.

Comment: Go Hillary 2020!

Comment: Death Note in the hands of a extreme feminist ring? Due to the loose definition of politician and the heterogen of world politics you will need thousands of people to hand pick most of it's targets. Example, there's a ex Governor and actual senator is just a figure head and puppet of his sister the actual politician behind this twerp. Who ill be killed here?

Comment: Future studies will find high correlation between misogyny and contempt for politicians

Answer (score 2):

Most democratic countries will be completely unaffected, the UK has been a monarchy ruled by a matriarch for over 65 years, the middle east will be amusing until Sheikhs to be start electing their wives as figureheads, North Korea collapses into civil war and is overtaken by the south.

Comment: The present leader of North Korea (NK) has a sister. So presumably do other members of the ruling Party. They will take over. China will step in to prevent NK collapsing. SK will have to install their own new all-female leadership.